# for every K>1 and natural there is an arithmetic progression with coprime numbers, can't prove this

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, euclidean-algorithm

I have the following question:

Prove that for every $ K  \in \mathbb{N} , K\gt 1$ there exists an arithmetic progression with length K of co prime numbers.
the numbers themselves aren't necessarily prime. but they are co prime.

define how to choose the common difference and why it works ?

I am having a struggle proving this, I had a feeling its related to induction and or euclid

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem)

Comment: not exactly what i need

Comment: Start by investigating what you need to avoid. Suppose you have a $K$-term arithmetic progression with common difference $d$. If two terms have a common prime factor $p$, what can you say about $p$? After having found that out, it's not too difficult to construct a coprime $K$-term progression.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are infinitely many AP's exist $\forall K$.
Let all elements of the sequence be odd, therefore the increment is even.
Let $r ≥ max⁡(K-1,2)$
and $d = r\#$, where $\#$ is the [primorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), factorial could be used instead.
Let $A = \{1, 2, ..., K - 1\}$.
Let the starting term be $a_1 = d + 1$ (it could be parameterized by multiplying $d$ with an integer, so that even $a_1 = 1$),
and let the increment be $d$ (again, it could be parameterized by multiplying with an integer),
so any other term is $a_i = d + 1 + \alpha d$, $\alpha \in A$.
If the elements have a common prime factor, then it divides their difference, and vice versa, if it divides their difference, then it must divide the elements.
Any two elements' difference is $\beta d$, $\beta \in A$, and no prime factor of this divides any $a_i$ or $a_1$.